# SSIS работа переменных в ODBC

Tags: odbc, variable, ssis

Из ODBCsource нужно загрузить строки, pay_id которых больше чем pay_id у строк в моей таблице OLEDBdestination. 
Создал SQL task, выбрав максимальный pay_id:

```
select pay_id from test_lotomat where pay_id = (select max(pay_id) from test_lotomat ) ;
```

Создал переменную Variable, присвоил ей результат запроса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал точку останова, запустил пакет, увидел что в переменную записывается значение. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее в Потоке данных добавил ODBCsource, прописал в нем запрос с переменной:

```
select * from pays_ext where pay_id > @Variable limit 50;
```

естественно добавил и OLEDBdestination и связал с источником данных.
 Текст запроса прекрасно работает в DBeaver, с помощью заренее заданной переменной. А В SSIS нет, получаю пустые строки. Что я делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В SSIS оно так не работает. Варианты, как сделать в SSIS:

1. Сделать в OLEDB Source параметризованный запрос вида
   `select * from pays_ext where pay_id > ? limit 50;`
   и сопоставить переменную `Variable` нулевому параметру запроса.
2. Сделать строковую переменную `SQL_Query` и в выражении для нее написать
   `"select * from pays_ext where pay_id > "+(DT_WSTR, 10)[User::Variable]+" limit 50;"`
   Затем в OELDB Source - указать, что вы хотите получить данные из SQL запроса в переменной, и указать в качестве переменной - созданную ранее `SQL_Query`.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена путем создания Linked Server и использования Openquery.